# Are there vs code extentions like live server for app development with kivy or python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

i would like to know if there are vs code extentions you can use to see live updates when changing your .kv file..it does not have to be an extention...it can be a built in feature or perhaps a piece of code i can place in my .py file that tells the code to run the .py file automatically when changes are made to the corresponding .kv file??

...i am new to python and vs code so i am unsure if if this is even possible??

My idea is basically....

If .kv file is saved then run the .py file...

But i don't know how to write that in python...would i be able to write the if statement in the actual python file or would i have an external .py file to complete this action??

Comment: If you use Pycharm, you can just press a single button to run your code.

Comment: There isn't a built-in feature in Visual Studio Code. You can try to use a task runner like `nodemon` which is typically used in Node.js development but can be used to watch any type of file.

Comment: VS Code lets you run whatever Python file you're working on by clicking a "Play" button at the top of the editor. You can also open the command palette and select `Python: Run File in Terminal` - this will tell the built-in terminal to start Python and run your script. If you're coming from webdev and looking for live reload, I'm not aware of any way to do that in a Python environment, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a WYSIWYG GUI editor use QT. There are no first-party tools for doing this with Kivy.

There is an extension on VSCode that triggers a task when a file is saved. You can configure it to run the Python script. It would get annoying quickly though. Every time you save your Python script will run and a new window will pop up. Run the Python script instead. it is not hard to invoke a Python script from your terminal.

Comment: Going the "Task" route would also be a nightmare for folks who have autosave turned on. Sure it works, but at what cost?! Agreed: just run it in the terminal.